# React - Should I replace my css files with styled components

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styles, styled-components

My question may turn out to be a little strange, but I want to understand, for example, I have 10 css files in my project and these styles are 90% not repeated. Is it worth using styled components in this case? i.e. replace all these styles with an object?

```
const Button = styled.button`
  font-size: 2em;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
`;
```

I understand that styled components have a lot of advantages. But I want to understand if it is worth replacing the content of 10 css files with styled components? Because perhaps in the future I will need this technology

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask), [*What types of questions should I avoid asking?*](/help/dont-ask), and [*What topics can I ask about here?*](/help/on-topic) This is a matter of opinion, and so it's off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think so. If they are not repeatable and reusable and you already have a lot of CSS codes and files, it will take a long time to convert them to Style-component, and also it won't bring too much advantage. Besides the advantages of styled-components, there are some disadvantages too as it is a pure JS and if it is not reusable, it is basically increasing your payload size. SO definitely in your case, I think you should stick to CSS for now.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but let me ask one more question about this theme I have applied dark and light theme in my project when turning on dark mode I have to check the `value` if it is dark then I have to change the color of my text to white the problem is that I have a lot of text in different files, can I leave the css untouched except for the text, that is, use styled components only for the text, because with it I get rid of the repetition of the code

Comment: Technics,  yes you can.